# Google sign in oauth2 403 error, disallowed_useragent

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In my PHP web application, users can sign-in with their Google accounts. The auth flow works fine, but there is one case, when I am getting an error while sign-up via Google account. Say, I shared my app link to a user via Skype. He/she opens Skype app on their iPhone device, click on the app link and press sign in via Google button. As a result, I am getting 403 error, disallowed_useragent.

I read, that Google doesn't longer support OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views”. The recommendation is to use devise  web browser. However, I am a little confused here, as how can I tell my app to open user's devise web browser.

Does any one can help me and explain how should I deal with this Google restriction?

Answer (score 0):

It is the app which has to show the login page in the web browser, in Android this can be done with using `Custom Tabs`, in IOS with the `SFSafariViewController`. Those controls use the native browser to show the login page and prevent the app from sniffing the user entered password (as you could do with the WebView).

It is not clear to me if it is your own app which tries to open the login page or if it is done from Skype, both are mentioned in the question. If it is your own app, you can use those controls, otherwise there is not much you can do, because you cannot control how a third party app handles the login.